# "ValueError: If your data is in the form of a Python generator, you cannot use `validation_split`." in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am following [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/hub_with_keras) to train the model on my own categories and using validation_split in model.fit() to see the validation accuracy. Here is the code:

```
model.fit((item for item in image_data), epochs=30, 
                steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,callbacks = [batch_stats], validation_split=0.33)
```

Doing so I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\phd python projects\tensorflow_img_class\src\tensorflow_img_class.py", line 65, in <module>
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,callbacks = [batch_stats], validation_split=0.33)    
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 758, in fit
    y, sample_weight, validation_split=validation_split)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 955, in check_generator_arguments
    raise ValueError('If your data is in the form of a Python generator, '
ValueError: If your data is in the form of a Python generator, you cannot use `validation_split`.
```

I am not able to find the solution for this error. How can I see the validation scores without loading validation data from separate directory? I want my original training data to be get spitted for the purpose of validation. Is it possible? What are the other options?

UPDATE
After following the solution fron KRUXX I am getting this error after it runs for first epoch which points to the model.fit line

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lambda_input to have shape (224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)
```

Comment: Im not familiar with Tensor flow, but is there a reason you are using a generator? maybe you can try a list? [item for item in image_data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you followed [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/hub_with_keras) example. You can try to split the data when you are initializing `ImageDataGenerator` like this,

```py
image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, validation_split=0.33)

image_data_train = image_generator.flow_from_directory(str(data_root),subset='training')
image_data_val = image_generator.flow_from_directory(str(data_root),subset='validation')
```

Here [`subset`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) use to specify training and validation generator. And you can use `validation_data` paramerter to pass the validation images in `model.fit`.

```py
model.fit((item for item in image_data_train), 
          epochs=1, 
          steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
          callbacks = [batch_stats], 
          validation_data = (item for item in image_data_val), 
          validation_steps =image_data_val.samples/image_data_val.batch_size )
```

**Update**

You need to use this `flow_from_directory` according to your requirements. Please read the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory).

```
image_data_train = image_generator.flow_from_directory(str(data_root), target_size=(224,224),subset='training')
image_data_val = image_generator.flow_from_directory(str(data_root), target_size=(224,224),subset='validation')
```

Comment: ```model.fit((item for item in image_data_train), 
          epochs=1, 
          steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
          callbacks = [batch_stats], 
          validation_data = (item for item in image_data_val), 
          validation_steps =image_data_val.samples/image_data_val.batch_size )``` Have you tried like this?

Comment: now it yields another error after first epoch, that I have updated in question itself

Answer (score 0):

The `keras.fit` method has the following signature:

```
fit(x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None, validation_freq=1)
```

where

> x = Numpy array of training data (if the model has a single input), or list of Numpy arrays (if the model has multiple inputs)

You cannot use a generator to split data as the generator doesn't load all results in the memory.

Example:

`x = (i for i in range(int(10e10)))`

`x` is now a `generator object` and its value can be accesed with `next` or a iterator can be generated with `iter`. `x` doesn't now hold all the integers from 0 to 10^10 in memory. This is called **lazy evaluation**. As `x` is not a list per-se you cannot use `validation_data`. A solution to this could be:

```
model.fit(np.array([item for item in image_data]), epochs=30, 
            steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch, callbacks = [batch_stats], validation_split = 0.33)
```

Other than that, 33% for validation could be a little too much. I usually go for 10-15% so try something between 10 - 25 % depending on your dataset  and/or your model.

Comment: I tried your option but it just does nothing. Normally, it runs with the following epochs immediately but after the above solution, it just stuck and does nothing. The program is though running but nothing happens on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try to change loss function from **spare_categorical_crossentropy** to **categorical_crossentropy**.